# Binding web version of pgadmin to gunicorn

Tags: django, gunicorn, pgadmin

I have a gunicorn file that is executing and correctly displaying the web together with nginx and supervisor

```
SOCKFILE=/home/boards/run/gunicorn.sock  

exec gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
  --log-level=debug \
  --log-file=-
```

but in addition to that, now I need to add pgadmin so as to be reachable like this: myweb.com/pgadmin

I have added a new location in my nginx file

```
upstream app_server {  
  server unix:/home/boards/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
```

Here below is the new added snippet:

```
 location /pgadmin4/ {
 include proxy_params;
 proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/pgadmin4.sock;   
 proxy_set_header X-Script-Name /pgadmin4;    
}


but I get a 502 bad gateway 
104764#104764: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/pgadmin4.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream,
```

UPDATE:
I would surely need to tell gunicorn that I have another app to care for, so I have found these options, yet no change so far ...

```
 --bind 0.0.0.0:80 --workers=13 --threads=25 --chdir /usr/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/pgadmin4 pgAdmin4:app
 
 --bind unix:/tmp/pgadmin4.sock --workers=13 --threads=25 --chdir ~/environments/my_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pgadmin4 pgAdmin4:app
```

UPDATE II:

I think I understand what the protocol is. at

```
/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pgadmin4
```

there is an executable python file.
I have run that and I get a message saying:

```
pgAdmin 4 - Application Initialisation
```

what I think it means by that is that it is creating a socket to the pgadmin4 app, which would be accessible through this

```
proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/pgadmin4.sock;
```

However, when I do that, I get the error mentioned. I don't know what the path is expected to be. Both the digital ocean tutorial and the pgadmin4 documentation tell the same story, they both have the same code as I write it